# Set Items Selected in a CheckComboBox

Tags: java-8, javafx-8, controlsfx

I´m using the CheckComboBox by ControlsFX for a Project and I want to set some of the Items Checked from the Start so I tried this Code in my initialize-Methode, but when i start the program, nothing is set Selected/Checked.

```
checkBox.getCheckedModel.check(1);
```

I´m using an ObservableList of Strings for the Box and got it build into my FXML file and everything works fine, but the CheckModel-thing refuses to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What JDK and ControlsFX versions are you using?

Comment: JDK 1.825, still not sure why i cant use it in my initialize method, but i used it combined with a selectionmodel of a tableview and now it is working. still thanks for you effort, when i find a solution i will post it!

Comment: And ControlsFX? 8.20.9 version is working for me. By the way `getCheckedModel` should be `getCheckModel()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you can try use the folllowing

```
CheckComboBox.getCheckModel().checkIndices(int...args);
CheckComboBox.getCheckModel().check(int);
CheckComboBox.getCheckModel().check(String);
```

These work for me