# Set the default selected checkboxes in a ControlsFX CheckComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

I'm trying to set the default selected value for a `ControlsFX CheckComboBox v8.0.3` with `Java 8`

I have tried the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890237/set-items-selected-in-a-checkcombobox), but when I try

```
CheckComboBox.getCheckModel().check(0);
```

I get a class can not be referenced from a static context. When I try the following I get cannot resolve method check(int);

```
final CheckComboBox<String> checkComboBox = new CheckComboBox<>(strings);
checkComboBox.getCheckModel().check(0);
```

If I try `getCheckmodel().selectIndices(0)` the first `All1` is populated to the `CheckComboBox` only when a new value is selected from the `CheckComboBox`. Is there a way to refresh the `comboxBox` after selecting the indices or any other way to achieve what I want?

```
Text numberTypeText = new Text("Features supported:");
final ObservableList<String> strings = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
strings.add("All1");
strings.add("All2");
strings.add("All3");
strings.add("All4");
strings.add("All5");
strings.add("All6");
strings.add("All7");
strings.add("All8");

final CheckComboBox<String> checkComboBox = new CheckComboBox<>(strings);
        checkComboBox.getCheckModel().selectIndices(0);

checkComboBox.getCheckModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {
    public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) {
        System.out.println(checkComboBox.getCheckModel().getSelectedItems());
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try the following I get cannot resolve method check(int);

It is because you are using very old version of ControlsFX. Upgrade your ControlsFX to newer version.

> If I try getCheckmodel().selectIndices(0) the first All1 is populated to the CheckComboBox only when a new value is selected from the CheckComboBox.

This seems like a bug which is fixed in newer version of ControlsFX.

In v8.40.14, I was able to set the default checkboxes using `check()` method:

```
checkComboBox.getCheckModel().check(0);
```

Or, `checkIndices()` method if you want to check multiple items:

```
checkComboBox.getCheckModel().checkIndices(0, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I had to update Java to version 8u40 as well